# Variation table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

I have installed the package `tkz-tab` to make sign and variation tables of a function. Signs are okay but when I try to make a variation table, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab} %loads tikz

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It writes:

> Package pgf error: No shape named F11 is known. See the pgf package
>   for details.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome! Please add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` under `\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  `tkz--tab`loads `TikZ`

Answer (score 3):

#### New answer

Disabling the `-` character shorhand with the `\shorthandoff` macro in the `babel` package makes it work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab} %loads tikz

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{-}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\shorthandon{-}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

It works by adding tikz's babel library: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This precisely [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528478/variation-table#comment1336478_528478) which you are repeating here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat As it seems to be an answer, posting it as such is reasonable, although I might have gone for pinging you to ask you to do so yourself

Comment: @JosephWright Well, I'd agree with that if that was the first occasion. Unfortunately this is a repeating theme. (The reason why I did not write an answer is that Alain Matthes is around, he would be a good choice for writing this answer, but not the current OP.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat be calm please! just a small thing. Btw, what do you think about my way of drawing variation tables? a bit long but flexible

Answer (score 3):

You have the solution ... Your problem appears with `babel` and the option `czech`. You have three solutions. The best `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` or  you can avoid using `babel` and finally  another solution is to use `lualatex` with `polyglossia`.

In the code below, I used the `help' option to show you all the nodes created by my package. This allows you to customize the table easily.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[help]{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can like Black Mild use  `xscale` and `yscale`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5,xscale=.8]
\tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

You can also add style like in `TikZ` because it's `Tikz` behind `tkz-tab`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5,xscale=.8]
  \tikzset{h style/.append style = {%
 pattern=north east lines,pattern color=purple}}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ / 2}{$-\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, $2$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +C/ $0$, +H/ $0$, D-/ $-10$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: [I was hoping you'd answer this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528478/variation-table?noredirect=1#comment1336592_528494).

Answer (score 2):

In case one likes plain TikZ. I adjust a bit the positions of nodes `0` and `-10`. Use `xscale` and `yscale` as you think fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.8,xscale=1.75]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=violet] (3.5,-1) rectangle +(1,-3);
\draw (0,0) rectangle +(6,-4) (0,-1)--+(0:6) (1,0)--+(-90:4);
\draw[gray] (2.5,-1)--+(-90:3) (3.5,-1)--+(-90:3) (4.5,-1)--+(-90:3);
\end{scope}
\path
(0,0)    node{$x$}          % <<< line 1
++(0:1)  node{$-\infty$}
++(0:1)  node{$-5$}
++(0:1)  node{$-3$}
++(0:1)  node{$2$}
++(0:1)  node{$+\infty$};
\path[nodes={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
(0,-2)   node{$f(x)$}          % <<< line 2
++(0:1)  +(-90:1) node (A) {$-\infty$}
++(0:1)  +(90:.5) node (B) {$0$}
++(0:1)  +(90:.5) node (C) {$0$}
++(0:1)  +(-90:.5) node (D) {$-10$}
++(0:1)  +(90:1) node (E) {$+\infty$};
\draw[-stealth,blue] (A)--(B);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (B)--(C);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (D)--(E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```